# How to translate Trac custom content added with site.html?

Tags: html, localization, internationalization, trac, genshi

We have customized our Trac instance to display additional content to the [newticket page](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/newticket), with the following `site.html` file (as explained in [documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#SiteAppearance)):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      py:strip="">
    <form py:match="div[@id='content' and @class='ticket']/form[@action='/newticket#ticket']" py:attrs="select('@*')">
      <div class="warning">
        <p>You are about to create a new JOSM ticket.
        </p>
        <p>Please make sure to always use this link in <a href="wiki/Help/Action/About">About Dialog</a> (Shift-F1) to come here:</p>
        <img src="raw-attachment/wiki/Help/Action/About/bugreport_small.png" alt="Bug report link in About dialog" height="53" width="361" />
        <p>Clicking on this link prefills the bug report with useful information for us (<a href="wiki/Help/Action/ShowStatusReport">Status Report</a>).
        </p>
        <p>In any case, don't be shy :) Please let us a way to contact you if needed (either by <a href="register">creating an account</a> or entering your e-mail address below (it won't be publicly visible but will allow us to reach you, and you will be notified about ticket progress).
        </p>
      </div>
      ${select('*')}
    </form>
</html>
```

I don't see anything in the documentation about translation. How can we translate this text now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally come up with a small JavaScript solution.

It's simple when you only need a few languages with a text that doesn't change:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      py:strip="">
    <form py:match="div[@id='content' and @class='ticket']/form[@action='/newticket#ticket']" py:attrs="select('@*')">
      <div class="warning">
        <table style="border:0; border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:0 10px" class="wiki">
        <tr><td style="background:#FFFC75; border:1px solid #ccc; border-right:0" valign="top">
        <p id="josm_warning_01">You are about to create a new JOSM ticket.
        </p>
        <p id="josm_warning_02">Please make sure to always use <a href="wiki/Help/Action/ReportBug">Help/Report bug</a> or this link in <a href="wiki/Help/Action/About">About Dialog</a> (Shift-F1) to come here:</p>
        <img src="raw-attachment/wiki/Help/Action/ReportBug/reportbug.png" alt="Bug report menu entry" height="84" width="207" />
        <img src="raw-attachment/wiki/Help/Action/About/bugreport_small.png" alt="Bug report link in About dialog" height="53" width="361" />
        </td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">

if (navigator.language.indexOf('fr') == 0) {
  document.getElementById("josm_warning_01").innerHTML = 'Vous êtes sur le point de créer un nouveau ticket JOSM.';
  document.getElementById("josm_warning_02").innerHTML = 'S\'il vous plaît, assurez-vous de toujours utiliser <a href="wiki/Help/Action/ReportBug">Aide/Rapporter un bug</a> ou ce lien dans la <a href="wiki/Help/Action/About">fenêtre À propos</a> (Shift-F1) pour venir ici:';

} else if (navigator.language.indexOf('de') == 0) {
  document.getElementById("josm_warning_01").innerHTML = 'Sie sind dabei, ein neues JOSM-Ticket zu erstellen.';
  document.getElementById("josm_warning_02").innerHTML = 'Bitte nutzen Sie immer <a href="wiki/De:Help/Action/ReportBug">Hilfe → Fehler melden</a> oder diesen Link im <a href="wiki/De:Help/Action/About">"Über JOSM..."-Fenster</a>, um hierher zu gelangen:';
}
      </script>
      ${select('*')}
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not easy until something like the [proposal for custom labels](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/Proposals/ConfigEnumTranslation) has been realized.

Currently it requires adding your additional msgids to Trac core PO files and recompiling and installing that custom Trac version - quite ugly and not remotely as modifiable as the template.

Providing custom translations within a plugin would not be effective, because plugin translations would reside in a translation domain, that is not evaluated for Trac core templates like the (new) ticket page.

Comment: OK thanks for the info. Well, we won't translate it, then, too complicated for very little gain :)